# jQuery.mobile.loadPage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery Mobile I have produced a mobile app with many pages all in one HTML which is fine but takes time to load and reload if needed.

I want to divide this into several separate HTML docs. I have seen somewhere you do this within the `<body>`  section.  I have tried `jQuery.mobile.loadPage` with `pageContainer` but can not get this to work.

Are there any examples of this working?

Comment: How many pages and how large are the pages? you realize that just linking pages using the traditional anchor tag, the framework, by default, uses AJAX to load all of your content. So if you preload the pages using data-prefetch attribute this should help. Also cache all your pages.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data-preload` and `data-dom-cache="true"` you can choose which pages to preload into the DOM and which pages should be cached and retained even when "navigating away" from said page (on the same domain).

I have a somewhat working example, it's a in-development site; client wanted to see some progress. login with username "foo" password "bar" http://dmcweb.hostoi.com/index.php